# Button in a row in a h:panelGrid

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I want to style all my buttons in a row on the left site of my input Field:

However, at the moment it looks like that, because I use `styleClass="grid"`:

[image]

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value" styleClass="grid"
    style="margin-bottom: 10px">

    <h:outputText value="#{templateItem.label}"
        rendered="#{templateItem.displayType == 1}" />
    <p:inputText value="#{orderListBean.value}"
        rendered="#{templateItem.displayType == 1}" required="false"
        id="inputText">
    </p:inputText>

    <!-- Command Buttons -->
    <h:panelGrid columns="5" styleClass="grid" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
        <div>
            <h:commandLink action="#{orderListBean.makeFirst(templateItem)}">
                <i class="icon-circle-arrow-up" />
            </h:commandLink>
            <h:commandLink action="#{orderListBean.moveUp(templateItem)}">
                <i class="icon-arrow-up" />
            </h:commandLink>
            <h:commandLink action="#{orderListBean.moveDown(templateItem)}">
                <i class="icon-arrow-down" />
            </h:commandLink>
            <h:commandLink action="#{orderListBean.makeLast(templateItem)}">
                <i class="icon-circle-arrow-down" />
            </h:commandLink>
            <h:commandLink action="#{orderListBean.deleteItem(templateItem)}">
                <i class="icon-remove" />
            </h:commandLink>
        </div>
    </h:panelGrid>

</h:panelGrid>
```

Any idea how to move my Buttons beside my input Field?
I really appreciate your answer!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `<div></div>` tags within the panel. They're classed as an element so are taking up the first column. That's why your remove icon is appearing on the next row

Also change the number of columns in your first panelGrid to 3